# change a for loop to a function to scrape a website

Tags: r, function

I am trying to scrape a website using the following:

```
industryurl <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/industries"

library(rvest)

read <- read_html(industryurl) %>%
  html_table()

library(plyr)
industries <- ldply(read, data.frame)
industries = industries[-1,]

read <- read_html(industryurl)

industryurls <- html_attr(html_nodes(read, "a"), "href")

links <- industryurls[grep("/industry/", industryurls)]

industryurl <- "https://finance.yahoo.com"

links <- paste0(industryurl, links)
links
##############################################################################################

store <- NULL
tbl <- NULL

for(i in links){
  store[[i]] = read_html(i)
  tbl[[i]] = html_table(store[[i]])
}


#################################################################################################
```

I am mostly interested in the code between `##########` and I want to apply a function instead of a `for loop` since I am running into time out issues with yahoo and I want to make it more human like to extract this data (it is not too much).

My question is, how can I take `links` apply a function and set a sort of delay timer to read in the contents of the `for loop`?

I can paste my own version of the `for loop` which does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function I came up with

```
##First argument is the link you need
##The second argument is the total time for Sys.sleep

extract_function <- function(define_link, define_time){
         print(paste0("The system will stop for: ", define_time, " seconds"))
         Sys.sleep(define_time)
         first <- read_html(define_link)
         print(paste0("It will now return the table for link", define_link))
         return(html_table(first))
}

##I added the following tryCatch function
       link_try_catch <- function(define_link, define_time){
       out <- tryCatch(extract_function(define_link,define_time), error = 
       function(e) NA)
       return(out)
}

##You can now retrieve the data using the links vector in two ways
##Picking the first ten, so it should not crash on link 5

p <- lapply(1:10, function(i)link_try_catch(links[i],1))

##OR (I subset the vector just for demo purposes

p2 <- lapply(links[1:10], function(i)extract_function(i,1))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This works great! very informative also, thanks you a lot!

Comment: One question the `lapply(1:5...` I changed to `lapply(1:length(links)` and it stops are `5`, however there are 214 links to extract. I get this error `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.`

Comment: Let me take a look

Comment: The error is a 503 error, which means, roughly, that there is a problem on the server side and it cannot fulfill the request. The code should work if you remove the problematic link.
Source for the 503 error: http://www.itpro.co.uk/web-browser/30394/what-is-http-error-503-and-how-do-you-fix-it

Comment: hmm it seems like the link `https://finance.yahoo.com/industry/Manufactured_Housing` is causing it to break. Which is also broken on the Yahoo finance link here, `https://finance.yahoo.com/industries `

Comment: Okay removing that particular like from the `links` vector seems to have solved the issue up until another bad URL. Would a `tryCatch` addition work here to skip over errors?

Comment: I am still getting ` Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.`

Comment: I ran the links vector in batches (first 100, then 101 to 200, then 201 to 214). These are the links that were flagged as having a bad connection on my machine:
https://finance.yahoo.com/industry/Manufactured_Housing
https://finance.yahoo.com/industry/Music_Video_Stores
https://finance.yahoo.com/industry/Medical_Practitioners
The new code worked fine for me

Comment: Okay I was able to locate and remove those 3 bad links that you mentioned and now it seems to be working (I still have one or two bad links to remove)